# How to Move a Survey List from SharePoint Online to SharePoint 2010 Environment

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, environment

I am putting together a simple survey for a customer but I do not yet have access to his SharePoint 2010 environment. However, one of my colleagues does. I'd like to create the survey in a SharePoint Online (Office 365) environment, export the page and its contents to my colleague who can then import that page into the 2010 environment.

Other posts speak to how difficult this is and there may be no out-of-the-box way of doing it.

How can this be done easily?

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating the survey and then going into the list settings and Save as a template. This can then be exported, handed off, imported into the site, and then be used to create a new survey.

I haven't tried a "downgrade" export like this, so I don't know for certainty if the colleague will be able to import and provision off of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Eric Alexander. I created a list template from this survey and then imported the .stp file to another SharePoint Online environment and it worked just fine. It didn't work when I handed it off to my colleague who tried to import the file into a SP2010 environment. I got this error: Cannot complete this action. Please try again. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's possible that the stp has some version specific information in it that is preventing it from working in a version downgrade scenario. It might not be possible or easy (like extracting it as a cab, editing it, and repackaging it)